# Applescript if class else

Tags: if-statement, applescript

I have a applescript I have been using for a while and it works good:

```
set js to "document.getElementsByClassName('The_Class')[0].click();"

tell application "Google Chrome" to tell ¬
    the front window to tell ¬
    the active tab to ¬
    set jsResult to execute javascript js
```

Now I want to add a **if and else** to it. Like this but I can't find a way to solve it:

```
if the class ('The_Class') exist then

  set js to "document.getElementsByClassName('The_Class')[0].click();"

     tell application "Google Chrome" to tell ¬
       the front window to tell ¬
       the active tab to ¬
       set jsResult to execute javascript js

else

   tell application "Google Chrome" to activate

      tell application "System Events"
         keystroke "r" using {command down}
      end tell

end if
```

Comment: You will need to execute some javascript first in order to get the class/element, or are you just wanting to check for a tab?

Comment: As long as you are using **JavaScript**, use `tell application "Google Chrome" to execute active tab of window 1 javascript "location.reload();"` to reload the page, not  telling **System Events** to `keystroke "r" using {command down}`

Comment: Alternatively, you can `tell application "Google Chrome" to reload the front window's active tab`.  That said, I think @user3439894's suggestion is more appropriate in this situation, because rather than checking for the existence of `'The Class'` with the AppleScript code, do it inside the JavaScript code, by evaluating `document.getElementsByClassName('The_Class').length`.  So you might as well do it all in a single JS call.

Comment: @red_menace I just want to check if the class exist and if it does do one thing and if it not exist do something else :) I'm still stuck. Googling and trying but can not find a good solution.

Comment: @CJK does the .length do the check? I'm not follow

Comment: It returns the number of elements that were found whose class is `"The_Class"`, therefore, it will return `0` if none exist.